# Unable to update quantity attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I was working on an event listing/ticketing app. Everything was working fine until I changed a line in my controller and now I can't add the same event twice into my cart. I get "undefined method `save' for 2:Fixnum"

Cartitem Controller

def create

```
event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@cartitem = @cart.add_event(event.id)
respond_to do |format|
  if @cartitem.save
    format.html {redirect_to store_url}
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cartitem }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @cartitem.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Here is a snippet of the Cart model where the add_event method is located
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cartitems, dependent: :destroy

```
def add_event(event_id)
    current_item = cartitems.find_by(event_id: event_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = cartitems.build(event_id: event_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because a method always returns the **last line executed**.

That's why when you already have a **current_item**, the last command you execute is `current_item.quantity += 1`, which returns the value `2`.

What you should do is something like :

```rb
def add_event(event_id)
    current_item = cartitems.find_by(event_id: event_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = cartitems.build(event_id: event_id)
    end
    current_item
end
```

and everything should work just fine :)

Comment: Did it work ? Was there something missing in my answer ?